# Converting tchar[] to LPCWSTR

Tags: visual-c++, string-concatenation, wchar-t, tchar, string-conversion

I am using FindFirstFile to traverse through a directory to search a dll.

When I get the dll, I use the WIN32_FIND_DATA structure's cfilename to get the name of that dll.

Now, I want to pass the dll to the function LoadLibrary() which expects Absoulte path to the dll.

Here's the **Problem**: 
The cfilename of WIN32_FIND_DATA structure returns a TCHAR[] array, which is just the name of the dll, not its path. I Should concatenate the path to the name to get the Absolute path.

The LoadLibrary() expects a LPCWSTR as parameter.

I need help:
(1) To Convert the TCHAR[] returned by WIN32_FIND_DATA's cfilename to LPCWSTR
(2) to concatenate the above converted LPCWSTR with a predefined path (L"C:\dir\example\") to get absolute path.

Any nudge towards right answer will make my day :)

regards,
andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, LoadLibrary takes a LPCTSTR, so problem 1 is no longer an issue. Problem 2 is simple string concatenation.

Comment: Sorry for being a noob, I am a newbie in the world of C++. what's the best way to concatenate tchar[] and LPCWSTR? Also I declared UNICODE in my application, hence when I write LoadLibrary, the intellisense asks for a LPCWSTR.

Comment: If you compile with UNICODE, then tchar is the same as WCHAR. So there is nothing to convert. (If you compile without UNICODE, then tchar is the same as char, and intellisense will say that LoadLibrary takes a LPCSTR, so again, nothing to convert.)

Comment: @Raymond- Thank you. Best way to concatenate these into one?

Comment: All you asked for was a nudge, so I nudged you. You can research string concatenation on your own.